# Calling from mobile phone without using the cellular network

Tags: mobile, phone, geolocation

This has been in the news:
https://www.wired.com/story/fcc-fines-wireless-companies-selling-users-location-data/

Is there a way to make calls without using cell towers?

Also in this context: is it true that if one uses wifi only for calling, then the location is not sent?

Comment: You mean like Skype, Teams, Zoom, Meet, Duo, Whatsapp, etc. etc. etc.? Have you looked up the term "wifi calling"?

Comment: netcat is still king

Comment: @schroeder The OP probably means using a WiFi connection to make "regular" mobile phone calls, even if there's no mobile signal. See for example [this Three page](http://www.three.co.uk/discover/three_intouch).

Comment: @TripeHound right: "wifi calling"

Answer (score 2):

I think you are interpreting the article the wrong way. This is not about **calling** but about locating the mobile phone. These location information are available to the provider whenever the mobile phone connects to the mobile network, no matter if you are doing a call, surfing or even if the mobile phone simply is on but idle.

If you don't want this you need to deactivate the mobile functionality, ideally by not using a mobile phone in the first place. Some protection is offered by not having a SIM. But as schroeder points out in the comment, the phone will still somehow connect to a mobile network. Otherwise emergency calls without SIM would not be possible. And the phone will likely identify itself against the network.

If you have some form of other network connection (like connecting to a WiFi Hotspot) you can use  Voice over IP solutions (Skype and many others) to make calls - as long as the other person can receive these calls. Some of the VoIP providers also offer (paid) POTS connectivity so that you can reach others which just have a normal phone and no VoIP app.

Comment: I have phones without SIM cards, and I get network time and other network features.

Comment: @schroeder: Do you mean "network" in the broad sense (i.e. time using NTP but maybe through WiFi) or in the context of "mobile network"? In the latter case you would need some kind of SIM (maybe eSIM) in my opinion since otherwise it will not connect to the mobile network.

Comment: I travel with them and even without connecting to wifi I get time and location updates. I *believe* that I can even make emergency calls (I get a notification every once in a while saying that I can). I can't test or confirm at the moment, but my impression has been that these devices still connect to the cell network even without a SIM.

Comment: @schroeder: Good point, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Tracking the location of a phone without SIM is likely done by using the phone's [IMEI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity), instead of the SIM's [IMSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_mobile_subscriber_identity). I wish I could have found a source for my claim.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at "WiFi calling". This is a feature that exists quite a while at least in my region (within Switzerland). Not all phones might support this, but at least some iPhone models do.

Most people use this at their home location, when they have bad coverage from the mobile network, but have a good WiFi access point at home. You could use it at every WiFi router accessible to you. However, I am not sure how this behaves with regard to geolocation data. I never tried that personally, but acquaintances do.

Have a look e.g. from these providers, Salt ans Swisscom, which are well-known in Switzerland:

- https://salt.ch/en/wifi-calling
- https://www.swisscom.ch/en/about/news/2015/08/20150827-MM-Bessere-Empfangsqualitaet-mit-WiFi-Calling.html

They explicitly say it also works from abroad.

Answer (score -1):

### Short Answer:

Check out goTenna for point-to-point voice and text:

## https://gotenna.com/

---

### Long Answer:

#### What Do You Really Want?:

There are lots of considerations here with multiple options.

- **Threats to Privacy?** - First, start by planning what you're trying to keep private and what threat actors your willing to protect
  yourself from.
- **Hardware?** - Second, almost no modern smartphone will function while respecting your privacy. Apple's iOS and Android aren't phones,
  they're Apple's and Google's data mining products at the core.
- **Functionality?** - Third, plan your use case. If you want to be able to search Google from your phone, you're never going to have privacy.

#### Some Options:

- **DIY Cell Network:** You can effectively setup your own mesh cell network. There was a product called goTenna that was a nice portable stick that provided a 4-mile range for voice and text. https://gotenna.com/ (Note, radio signals can still be triangulated even if you're not connected to a tower. However, if the handsets aren't registered to you that can maintain anonymity at least.)
- **WiFi Calling:** As Marcel pointed out, WiFi calling could bypass cell towers. However, it doesn't preserve location privacy. It just transfers it.
- **Tunneling:** This is the age old attempt to privately send information over a private network. Like a VPN is intended to send private communication over untrusted networks. A tunnel for voice or text could include a strong VPN and a private messaging app. Signal is a decent app yet not perfect. Signal does encrypt calls and messaging that it transmits over networks. This doesn't prevent location services.
- **Privacy Centric Device** - Something like https://puri.sm/ is focused on giving you as much privacy as possible on your devices. This won't prevent you from being triangulated by a government, but if you care about not being tracked by a big tech company you'd have to start with a privacy focused device.
- **Radio** - There are radios, not phones, that provide voice and/or basic text communications. CB, HAM, or other Software Defined Radio can provide for communication. I'm not aware of any smartphone hardware that doesn't have some location hardware on it. I wouldn't be surprised if there were some sort of FCC or 911 service mandate for handsets to include some form of locator ability.